# jQuery how to change class of one <td> based on id of another <td>

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have two tables and I want to highlight a cell in table 1 when I hover over another cell in table 2.  Not sure how to get there from here.  I'm thinking I should take the id from table 2 and look for the same id thing in table 1 and add the highlight class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <style> 
.cell {    background-color:#FFCC00 } 
.cell-highlight {    background-color:green } 
</style> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<table border='1' id='table-1'>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell' id='cell-0-0'>Cell 0,0</td><td class='cell' id='cell-0-1'>Cell 0,1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell' id='cell-1-0'>Cell 1,0</td><td class='cell' id='cell-1-1'>Cell 1,1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table border='1' id='table-2'>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell' id='t2cell-0-0'>2 Cell 0,0</td><td class='cell' id='t2cell-0-1'>2 Cell 0,1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='cell' id='t2cell-1-0'>2 Cell 1,0</td><td class='cell' id='t2cell-1-1'>2 Cell 1,1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script> 
  var id;
  $("td.cell").mouseover(function() { 
    id=$(this).find("id");
    $(this).addClass('cell-highlight' ); 
  }).mouseout(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('cell-highlight' ); 
  }); 

</script> 

</body>
```

Comment: You will need to change your IDs to be valid.  IDs cannot start with a number.

Comment: IE did not seem to mind :-).  I will.

Comment: @jfriend00 - In HTML5 ID's can start with a number.  http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @mrtsherman - why cause yourself potential problems when running in older browsers?  There's just no reason to add this potential complication.  Start the IDs with a letter and then you don't have to worry about compatibility issues, but it is good to know that they cleaned this up in HTML5.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I didn't say he shouldn't just that he can. Making people aware of deprecated rules helps push people into understanding using new technologies instead of getting mired down in old stuff.

Comment: @mrtsherman - your comment implies that he needn't change anything and adds nothing about compatibility with older browsers.  Maybe you're acknowledging that issue now, but your comment by itself did not which is why I added info about that.  This is hardly an example of "new technologies".  It's an example of cleaning up a spec to relax a very minor syntax restriction who's original reason for being there is probably no longer an issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I was very clear that HTML5 supports id's that begin with a number. How is that misleading? Do I need to then hold his hand and explain what HTML5 is? If HTML5 isn't new then I don't know what is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes it your code

```
$("td.cell").mouseover(function() { 
    id=$(this).attr("id");
    $(this).addClass('cell-highlight' ); 
    secondid = "#t2"+id;
    $(secondid).addClass('cell-highlight');
  }).mouseout(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('cell-highlight' );
    id=$(this).attr("id");
    secondid = "#t2"+id;
    $(secondid).removeClass('cell-highlight'); 
});
```

Comment: Also, acknowledge what @jfriend00 has mentioned in his comments, avoid starting a ID with a number and make the necessary changes to the code above

Comment: This worked a treat. Once I fixed the case of the functions in your code. I hate case sensitive code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index and eq functions of jQuery to identify the position in table-1 of the highlighted cell. Then mirror this selection in table 2.

http://jsfiddle.net/SfGZV/2

```
$('#table-1 td').mouseover( function() {
    var row = $(this).parent('tr').index();
    var cell = $(this).index();

    $('#table-2 td.active').removeClass('active');        
    $('#table-2 tr').eq(row).children('td').eq(cell).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Nice idea.  But I'm not sure that each table with have equivalent number of rows and columns.

Comment: I like the jsfiddle site.  PS: Fixed your code so it removes the active class.

Comment: @Martlark - yeah, I like jsfiddle a lot. It cleanly separates your code html/css/js. Plus it is great that you can quickly grab the same jQuery library as someone else.